PostgreSQL Check Right before Transaction closes
i have the following tables:
tenants:

tenantId (UUID)
invoiceAddress (TEXT)

packages:

packageId
needsInvoice

tenants_and_packages:

tenantsAndPackagesId
tenantId
packageId

This is a M2N-Mapping between Tenants and Packages.
What is the problem?
I want to achieve the following "Check"-Logic. I want to make sure that when I insert/update a tenant or package, it will be checked whether the tenant needs to have the column invoiceAddress set or not (it depends from the needsInvoice column of the Packages-Table.
Now, because sometimes I only edit the tenant, sometimes only the package and sometime both right after each other. But every time it runs in the context of a migration. Therefore, the "check" must be executed right before the transaction would finish (commit). Because, when I want to edit a tenant not to have the invoiceAddress set, because in the next step (same transaction-context) I want to set the package's needsInvoice to false, this kind of "check" cannot be executed right after the tenant has changed, since it would immediatly abort the transaction.
Thanks in advance! If any help for understanding is required, lmk!

Phynae

Hence the fact, that constraints do not allow subqueries or any dynamic logic, it won't work with them as far as I know.

Using triggers and functions is also not working since they are executed right before or after the row was inserted/updated.



You could use a deferred constraint trigger:
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER ...
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ...
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE ...

Such a trigger will run right before the commit of the transaction, just like you want.
But you should be aware that such a trigger will always suffer from race conditions if there are concurrent data modifications, because data modifications by a concurrent statement are not visible in the trigger function.
As detailed in my article, you either need the SERIALIZABLE isolation level or locking to serialize the operations if you want such triggers to work reliably.
Perhaps you can redesign your data model so that there are no constraints between columns of different tables...
